# Sustainable read speed for SSD possible?

Tags: ssd, usb-3

I have a project where I need to allow a user to connect an SSD (UASP) to a device (which has an embedded Mini ITX PC) and stream data (uncompressed video) at 370 MByte/second read speed.

I need to allow the user to connect the SSD to his own PC and create any (uncompressed video) content he wants and send it from his PC to the SSD, which he will later connect to the custom device for streaming his content.

In other words, files are going to be saved and deleted from the SSD by the user, however the read speed must remain the same and not go below 370 MByte/s for the device to be able to stream the files.

Is this possible? Leaving any damage or wear from old SSD aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the obvious: "Just get a really fast SSD."

Another option is to use some sort of caching option such as a RAM disk.

The main reason to use an SSD for workloads like you described is that they don't slow down due to fragmentation. While HDDs have to align themselves for every read/write, an SSD has no moving parts and can access any piece of data instantly.

Comment: RAMs won't work as the memory needs to be connected to user's PC for moving video files there, and then disconnected and connected to the device for streaming. Streaming directly from PC is also possible, but just one of the two ways (standalone/non standalone) of using the device.  As for just getting a fast SSD, my question comes more from fear of things such as fragmentation slowing down read speed over time.

Comment: Unlike HDDs fragmentation isn't an issue for SSDs as the way that they read and write is different. HDDs have to spin disks and move heads, which means that when files are closer physically, they are faster to read. SSDs don't have such limitations and it's actually harmful to defragment a SSD. TL;DR: SSD write/read speed doesn't decay over time.

Comment: Oh, so fragmentation isn't an issue with SSD? Awesome. If you can't think of anything similar , please add this part to the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added to the answer!